# how to compare 2 attributes of a class instance

Tags: python-2.7, class, compare

I need to compare every plane (x,y) points. If x or y of American planes is close by 1 than a `turn()` will apply and change to route of the plane.

Any ideas of how to compare each plane and check if it is close by one?

```py
import random

class CrazyPlane:

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def update_position(self):
        self.__x += random.randint(-1,1)
        self.__y += random.randint(-1,1)

    def get_position(self):
        return self.__x,self.__y

    def count_down(self):
        for i in range(10,0,-1):
            print i

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other

    def crash_check(planes):
        x = 0
        y = 1
        flag = True
        while (flag):
            if (__eq__(planes[x], planes[y])):
                print " BOOM!"
            else:
                y = y + 1
                if y == 3:
                    x = x + 1
                    y = x + 1
                    if x == 3:
                        flag = false
                        return False


###AND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####




def main():
    elal = CrazyPlane.CrazyPlane(1,2)
    american = CrazyPlane.CrazyPlane(3,4)
    british = CrazyPlane.CrazyPlane(5,6)
    lufthansa  = CrazyPlane.CrazyPlane(7,8)
    planes = [elal,american,british,lufthansa]
    flag = True

    while (flag):
        for plane in planes:
            plane.update_position()
            if crash_check(planes):
                flag = False
                print 'Crash'

main()
```

[View on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/c3BwAGUe)

Comment: Is this in Python?

Comment: yes python 2.7 i